# Set value of hidden field via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use Javascript to set the value of a hidden field.

I'm following an example that binds the value to a label thus:

```js
var input = $("#mobile-number"),
  output = $("#output"),
  input.on("keyup change", function() {
    var intlNumber = input.intlTelInput("getNumber");
    if (intlNumber) {
      output.text("International: " + intlNumber);
    } else {
      output.text("Please enter a number below");
    }
  });
```

That works, but I am trying to reproduce that by storing the value in a hidden field instead of displaying it in a label.

Comment: if the element identified with id `output` were an input with type hidden, you can use `output.val()` instead of `output.text()`

Comment: also change the comma after `output = $("#output"),` to a semicolon

Comment: html: `<input id="output" type="hidden" name="output">` and js: `output.val("your text");` (just as @daf suggested, if you didn't understand that..)

Comment: Thank You Guys for the guidance, Issue's been Resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hidden field is named as `output`, just substitute `text` function by `val` function, like this:

```
var input = $("#mobile-number"),
  output = $("#output"),
  input.on("keyup change", function() {
    var intlNumber = input.intlTelInput("getNumber");
    if (intlNumber) {
      output.val("International: " + intlNumber);
    } else {
      output.val("Please enter a number below");
    }
  });
```